# Why doesn't it delete the post?

Tags: php, mysql, database, key, sql-delete

I wrote this code to delete per click a post out of the database table 'community_posts'. When I click on the Button, it doesn't delete it, he get the URL with `do=delete&key=THEID` but it doesn't work, why? Can someone help me, please!

```
// PHP CODE
if($do == "delete" && is_numeric($key)){
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM community_posts WHERE id = '".$key."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($check) > 0){
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM community_posts WHERE id = '".$key."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
                $msg = "<center>Neuigkeit wurde erfolgreich gelöscht...</center>"; } else { $msg = "<center>Neuigkeit konnte nicht entfernt werden, versuche es erneut...</center>";
        }
}

// HTML CODE UND AUSGABE DER DATENBANK
<form action='' method='post'>
<?php $getComments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM community_posts ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 100"); ?>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getComments)){
$getUserInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$row['userid']."'");
$roww = mysql_fetch_array($getUserInfo); ?>

<div class="feedOne fade ptr">
        <div class="ph20">
                <div class="inner-1 lt" style=""><p style="color:#aeaeae;font-size:13px;"><a href="/community/userprofile/<?php echo $roww['username']; ?>" style="color:orange;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal;"><?php echo $roww['vorname']; ?></a> &raquo; Open Community</p>
                <p class=lt style="color:#aeaeae;font-size:11px;"><?php echo $row['posted_on']; ?></p><br />
                </div>
                <div class="rt inner-2">
                <p style="color:#333;font-size:13px;"><?php echo $row['story']; ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class=cl></div>
        </div>

<!-- BEI KLICK SOLL HIERMIT DER ENTSPRECHENDE BEITRAG GELÖSCHT WERDEN -->
<a href='<?php echo $path_admin; ?>/openfeed?do=delete&key=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'><img src="/assets/data/images/icons/delete_round.png" alt="delete" /></a>
<!---->

</div> 

<?php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: and how exactly you are getting $do & $key in `if($do == "delete" && is_numeric($key)){`

Comment: Most likely your if statements aren't evaluating the way you want. The delete code looks okay. I'm not sure doing an initial query to check for the row before deleting is necessary, but again, it looks like it should work if it is fired.

Comment: $do is == "delete", like you can see in the first line of PHP-Code, and the key I get with the output from the database-table community_posts

Comment: just an observation: the code looks rather antiquated, e.g. it apparently relies on `register_globals=On` which is `Off` by default (and with good reason) since PHP 4.2.0/July 2002. So, in case you're learning php from a book (or any other source) from around the year 2000 do yourself a favour and get a more recent book ;-) edit: and next thing on the list would be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 2):

Variables in the URL header are stored in the `$_GET` array. Instead your first line should be :

```
if($_GET['do'] == "delete" && is_numeric($_GET['key'])){
```

EDIT : You might want to check if the variable is set beforehand using the `isset()` method.

Comment: Man thank you very much, it works now and I have learned more about it, THANKS!

Comment: Just keep in mind that there are other issues with the script(s). Amongst them: using the deprecated mysql_* functions, not encoding the values from the database for safe usage in html output, not using an SQL JOIN but hammering the database server with one-at-a-time related queries, some superfluous code (like the SELECT before the DELETE) and so on and on.... there is still room for improvement ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign these two variables before you run an if statement on them:

```
// PHP CODE

if (isset($_GET['do'])){
    $do = $_GET['do'];
}
if (isset($_GET['key'])){
    $key = $GET['key'];
}

if($do == "delete" && is_numeric($key)){
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I do not see where do you assign values to the `$do` and `$key` variables. Here is what you have to do:

```
<?php
$do = !empty($_GET['do']) ? $_GET['do'] : '';
//Prevent SQL injection
$key = !empty($_GET['key']) ? (int)$_GET['key'] : '';
// ALL OTHER PHP CODE GOES HERE

?>
```

Comment: Need a $ on the variable $key there